# Electron: Failed to load URL: file:///#

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, electron-builder, appimage

I've got a mysterious error in the build of my electron app.

The following error shows up when running the `AppImage`, but not in the dev setup:

`(node:41260) electron: Failed to load URL: file:///# with error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

There is no additional info or stacktrace.

I tried to set: `process.traceProcessWarnings = true` but this does not help.

I think the error appears in the main process, because it pops up in my terminal and not the dev tools.

What could be the problem? Or, how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the build `AppImage` does not like links like `<a href="/#">...</a>`, but `href="javascript:;"` is fine.

One more reason to prefer buttons over empty href links...